# Is it possible to enable torch for expo-barcode-scanner?

Tags: javascript, android, react-native, expo

I have a simple qr-code reader app, and I wonder if can toogle the camera flashlight with a button.

```
const [torch, setTorch] = useState(false)

    <BarCodeScanner
    onBarCodeScanned={handleBarCodeScanned}
    style={{width:'100%', height:'100%'}}
    //Is there any flashlight modifier here?
    />

<Button title="turn on torch" onPress={()=>{setTorch(!torch)}}/>
```

Is this possible somehow?

Answer (score 2):

You can't do this with the `expo-barcode-scanner` module, but you can use the `expo-camera` module to scan barcodes and use the `flashMode` prop to turn on the camera flash.

Comment: Thanks! Could you maybe provide a small code snippet that works with the Button to turn on and off the torch? :)

Comment: I'll leave the coding up to you, but you'll want to turn on the flash in preview mode (I think) since you're not taking pictures but scanning barcodes. You can set `flashMode` to `FlashMode.torch` to turn it on while in preview mode, and set it to `FlashMode.off` to turn it off again.